# QT 5.12.1 Flicker issue in webengineview

Tags: windows, qt, qml, webgl, qtwebengine

Facing flickering issue while loading 3D web pages in qml webengineview.
But its works fine with nvidia but not works with INTEL uhd graphics 620.
Since the additional graphics card is too costly i wanted to find the solution from software end.
My ultimate aim is to be load the 3D web pages in qml qt without flicker issue in intel.